# ASPxGridview Dynamically Change Page Size

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm having an issue with the aspxgridview control. I have an aspxcombobox which allows the user to set a page size. Can anyone provide a proper example to achieve this. I've had it almost working but I get issues where the rows turn out to be blank.

My report is generated by clicking the a button, and I would also like them to change the page size without regenerating the report using callback

Comment: Page size as in the paging of the "aspxgridview"?...or page size as in the AspxReport page?

Comment: page sizing of the aspxgridview. rows per page.

Answer (score 1):

You will find this example available at:

[How to create a custom pager for the ASPxGridView with the "Selecting a page size" feature](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E1738.aspx)

Please note, the ASPxGridView is a pure server side control, and thus you won't be able to change its PageSize property without sending a request to the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
GridView1.PageSize = 3;
GridView1.DataBind();
```